# Как правильно запустить тяжелый php скрипт?

Tags: javascript, php, json, frontend, backend

Есть несколько страниц.
С каждой из них приходят post данные.
Далее на основании того что пришло с post, необходимо подготовить данные с помощью php и запустить функцию php.

После того как скрипт отработает, он в виде json сохраняет все что он делал в бд.
Далее необходимо воспроизвести этот json на фронте.

Вопрос в том: в каком порядке правильно обработать данные?
Есть вариант 1: когда придет post с любой из страниц, на той странице куда он пришел, запускать прелоадер, и ajax передавать данные post на файл в котором будет производиться тяжелая обработка, и когда она подойдет к концу, отдавать различные статусы. И если все успешно, делать еще один ajax запрос, брать данные из истории (брать json) убирать прелоадер, и стартовать фронт
Есть вариант 2: когда придет post, сразу на той же странице где будет фронт, обрабатывать post, и запускать там же тяжелый скрипт (тогда не смогу сделать прелоадер, так как php запускается первее js) как все отработает, сразу без дерганья json из бд, отдавать его на js, и он отрабатывает. Плюсы этого в том, что нету ajax запросов и данные не надо тащить, они уже рассчитались и есть на странице. Минусы в том что при долгой обработке, человек будет видеть пустую страницу.

Comment: Вы точно уверены что php? мне одному кажется с python nodejs, java будет проще жить с таким сценарием

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. Попробуйте объяснить на конкретном примере.